# s expects argument of type char c but argument 2 has type 'int' warning and bad return

Tags: c, arrays, string

Yes ,I know that this question was already asked for many times ,but none of these helped me to discover the problem (duplicate...yeah). I want to read from input a series of strings into an array and then search from 'First Name'. If the name exist ,I want to display all the data stored in that element of array (I attached the code to undestand easily). When I run it ,I read from keyboard all the data ,but it returns me absolutely nothing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct record {
    char name[10],lname[10],phone[10],bday[10];
};
void main() {
 struct record rec;
 char search;
 int i,nr;

printf("\nInput number of records: ");
scanf("%d",&nr);

for (i=0 ; i<nr ;i++) {
    printf("First name: ");
    scanf("%s",&rec.name[i]);
    printf("Last name: ");
    scanf("%s",&rec.lname[i]);
    printf("Phone: ");
    scanf("%s",&rec.phone[i]);
    printf("Bday: ");
    scanf("%s",&rec.bday[i]);
}

printf("Input the first name for searching: ");
scanf("%s",&search);

for (i=0 ;i<nr;i++) {
    if (search == rec.name[i]) {
        printf("First name: %s\nLast name: %s\nPhone: %s\nB-day: %s",rec.name[i],rec.lname[i],rec.phone[i],rec.bday[i]);
    } 
}

}
```

NOTE: I already replaced

```
scanf("%s",&rec.name[i]);
```

with

```
scanf("%s",rec.name[i]);
```

but no effect.

Comment: `char search;` is only one character. You cannot store string into it (`scanf("%s",&search);`).

Comment: if I replace with 'char search[10]' is not working as well

Comment: Did you use `scanf("%s", search)` instead? You also need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: and how did you change `if (search == rec.name[i])` ?

Comment: `char` is not a string like `"benny"`, it's a single character, like `'a'` or `'4'`. You want to have an array of records. (You should read some more about pointers, arrays, and strings in your fine C book. You can't learn these things by guessing.)

Comment: What you really need is to understand what you want...? Start changing `struct record rec;` to `struct record rec[DB_SIZE];` and moving the for indexes to rec, like `scanf("%s",rec[i].name);`

Comment: @RoadRunner I replace with `scanf("%s", search)` but nothing changed. @LPs ,I changed with `struct record rec[10]` and indexes but nothing happen

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: the `typedef` is not correct.  A `typedef` is used to give a name to some (usually user defined) type. like that `struct record`.  However to successfully do that, the `typedef` statement needs a 'trailing' name that will be used inplace of the original type definition.

Comment: there are only a couple of valid signatures for the `main()` function, they all have a return type of `int` (irregardless of what Visual C will (incorrectly) allow.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at at minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so no buffer overrun can occur (such overrun is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: this line: `if (search == rec.name[i]) {` will compare address pointers, probably not what you want.  Suggest using: `if( strcmp( search, rec.name[i] ) ==0) {`

Comment: this line: `struct record rec;` only defines a single instance of a `struct record`,  what you really want is to define an array of `nr` `struct record` instances.  Then the `scanf()` calls and the search loop need to look at the specific instance of the `struct record` in the array,  so the references to the fields should look similar to: ` rec[i].name` NOT `&rec.name[i]`

Comment: in modern C compilers, can use VLA arrays, so code sequence should be: `int nr; printf("\nInput number of records: ");
if( 1 != scanf("%d",&nr) ) { // handle error and exit }  struct record rec[nr];`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: in the definition of the `struct record`, the length of the fields are (in general) too short.  As an example, what if a persons phone number is: `306 976 4321`  or if it has a country code so it could be: `01 306 976 4321`

Comment: the input of the birthday, as with other prompts to the user, needs to be specific.  I.E. "enter birthday in format: MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: when ever calling printf() or fprintf(), etc either follow the call with a call to `fflush()`  or place a '\n' at the end of the format string  or immediately call some input function like `scanf().  Otherwise the output will sit in the associated stream output buffer until the buffer overflows or the program exits.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s",&search);` is expecting the variable `search` to be an array (at least) as long as the `rec[i].name field`  However, that variable is declared as a single character: `char search;`  it should be: `char search[10];` so it matches the associated field in the `struct record`.

Comment: the posted code uses several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 10, 10, 10, 10.  Strongly suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code.  One suggestion: `#definie MAX_NAME_LEN (9)  ... char name[ MAX_NAME_LEN+1] ...  scanf( "%" MAX_NAME_LEN "s", rec[i].name )  As the MAX CHARACTERS modifier has to be one less than the actual length of the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are a lot of problems with your code.

Firstly in this line:

```
scanf("%s",&search);
```

You have declared `search` as only a `char`, when really you want an array of chars. You also don't need `&` with `search`, as an array decays to a pointer to the first element.

It instead should be like this:

```
char search[10];
scanf("%9s", search); /* %9s to avoid buffer overflow */
```

You need to make this change to all your other `scanf()` calls, as this seems to be everywhere in this code.

It also seems that you want to create an array of records(structures), So you might need to make this after getting the value of `nr`. You can create it like this:

```
struct record rec[nr]; /* array of nr structures */
```

This also means calls like this:

```
rec.name[i]
```

Don't make sense, as you are iterating over the characters within a name, not over all the records in `struct records`.

This needs to be instead:

```
rec[i].name
```

Secondly, Your using `==` to compare strings, when you should be using [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) instead. Using `==` will only compare the base address of the strings, not the actual contents of strings.

Your line should be this instead:

```
if (strcmp(search, rec[i].name) == 0) {
```

If you read the manual page for `strcmp()`, checking for a return value of `0` means that both strings are equal in comparison.

Lastly, in your first `scanf()` call:

```
scanf("%d",&nr);
```

You should really check the return value of this:

```
if (scanf("%d", &nr) != 1) {
    /* exit program */
}
```

**Note:** For reading strings, you should really be using [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead. You can try upgrading to this later, but I think it is better to understand these basics first.

### Here is working example of what your program should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSIZE 10

typedef struct {
    char name[STRSIZE+1]; /* +1 to account for null-btye at the end */
    char lname[STRSIZE+1];
    char phone[STRSIZE+1];
    char bday[STRSIZE+1];
} record;

int main() {
    char search[STRSIZE+1];
    int i,nr;

    printf("\nInput number of records: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &nr) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    record rec[nr]; /* array of records */

    for (i = 0; i < nr ; i++) {
        printf("First name: ");
        scanf("%10s", rec[i].name);

        printf("Last name: ");
        scanf("%10s", rec[i].lname);

        printf("Phone: ");
        scanf("%10s", rec[i].phone);

        printf("Bday: ");
        scanf("%10s", rec[i].bday);
    }

    printf("Input the first name for searching: ");
    scanf("%10s", search);

    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        if (strcmp(search, rec[i].name) == 0) {
            printf("First name: %s\nLast name: %s\nPhone: %s\nB-day: %s\n",rec[i].name,rec[i].lname,rec[i].phone,rec[i].bday);
        } else {
            printf("Record not found.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The numeric input leaves a new line character in the input buffer, which is then picked up by the character input. when numeric input with `scanf()` skips leading white space, character input does not skip this leading white space.
Use a space before `%c` and it will help you cause if  space is not used then a buffer added with value .so that use space before `%c`

```
scanf(" %c",&rec.name[i]);
```